Is every balanced regular category exact?
A finitely complete category is said to be regular if coequalizers of kernel pairs exist and regular epimorphisms are stable under pullback. Also, a regular category is said to be exact if every internal equivalence relation is effective (a kernel pair).
A regular category is balanced (monic epimorphisms are isomorphisms) if and only if every epimorphism is regular.
So, is every balanced regular category automatically exact? If not, is it exact if it is additionally finitely cocomplete, or at least has coequalizers of equivalence relations?
Given any equivalence relation $E \rightrightarrows X$, if the category is finitely cocomplete, then the coequalizer (or "quotient object") $X \twoheadrightarrow X/E$ must exist. One could then take the kernel pair of that coequalizer to get another equivalence relation $E' \rightrightarrows X$. There is then an obvious monomorphism $E \rightarrowtail E'$ induced by the universal property of the kernel pair. If this monomorphism turns out to also be an epimorphism, then balancedness would imply that it is an isomorphism, making the original equivalence relation effective.

According to Michael Barr's paper Exact Categories, the category of Stone Spaces (compact Hausdorff totally disconnected spaces) is regular but not exact. Clearly monomorphisms are injective continuous functions. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624098/ shows epimorphisms are surjective continuous functions. It is then balanced because bijective continuous functions between compact Hausdorff spaces are homeomorphisms. Moreover, it is complete and cocomplete (e.g. because Stone duality shows it to be the opposite of Boolean algebras).
